What are the benefits of Saraswati ashttotara shatanamavali
What are the benefits of Saraswati ashttotara shatanamavali according to the Hindu scriptures . Does chanting it grant knowledge , intelligence memory , wisdom or is it just to get some special verbal abilities and communication skills?
